# Run configuration script at X session resume

Tags: scripts, suspend, power-management, xinput

On Ubuntu 13.04 I have to manually configure the touchpad since a bug prevents me using the standard configuration tool (changes don't save). However I created a script that sets up velocity, acceleration and scrolling, configured it to run at sartup and it works. The problem rises when I resume after suspension: especially the scrolling settings (the easiest to check) disappear.
Following other questions and answers I wrote this script (which contains the same commands I used in the over-mentioned one) located in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/ZZtouchpad`:

```
#!/bin/sh 
case "$1" in
    resume|thaw)
        xinput  --set-prop "CyPS/2 Cypress Trackpad" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 2
        xinput  --set-prop "CyPS/2 Cypress Trackpad" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 35
        xinput  --set-prop "CyPS/2 Cypress Trackpad" "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" -20, -20
esac
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Thnks for help!

**EDIT**

I found out that the script works when suspending with `pm-suspend` or `pm-suspend-hybrid`, but when suspending from the system menu or closing the laptop lid it doesn't. It seems the error is 'unable to connect to X server'.

So, the question better be rephrased: where should I put those commands for them to be executed when the X session is resumed? I tried `~/.xinitrc`, a file under `~/.xinitrc.d` and `~/.xsessionrc`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The issue is to connect to the X server. I solved it by stealing from `/etc/acpi/sleep.sh`. Put the following into `/etc/pm/sleep.d/99_setup_touchpad`.

```
#! /bin/sh

. /usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs

case "$1" in
    resume|thaw)
        if pidof xscreensaver > /dev/null; then
            for x in /tmp/.X11-unix/*; do
                displaynum=`echo $x | sed s#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##`
                getXuser;
                if [ x"$XAUTHORITY" != x"" ]; then
                    export DISPLAY=":$displaynum"
                    su $user -c "xinput set-prop 'CyPS/2 Cypress Trackpad' 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 2"
                    su $user -c "xinput set-prop 'CyPS/2 Cypress Trackpad' 'Device Accel Velocity Scaling' 35"
                    su $user -c "xinput set-prop 'CyPS/2 Cypress Trackpad' 'Synaptics Scrolling Distance' -20, -20"
                fi
            done
        fi
        ;;    
    *)
        # Nothing.
        ;;
esac
```

Finally make the file executable: `chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_setup_touchpad`.

*Note:* I'm usually the only one logged in via X on my laptop. So the loop is just one iteration. I don't know what happens if there are more than one sesssions live at the same time. The above is good enough for me.

Comment: I am too usually the only one logged in, but sadly this didn't work...