# run startup script which requires a xserver session

Tags: scripts, xorg, lightdm, quicklists

I have a python3-script which uses the `Gtk`-module (imported from `gi.repository`, for recent-manager functionality), requiring a link to the current xserver session (`lightdm` service in Ubuntu).

Running it manually via console (in a xserver session) works, but i want it to autorun.

An init.d script won't work (setting the DISPLAY variable to 0.0). Using `xvfb-run` made the init.d script run my script, but in a virtual xserver environment as expected (not mine). 
Is there no equivalent, which connects a init.d script to the current xserver-session?

So far i've tried an `.xinitrc` file (in `~/`, yes it is executable), as well as creating `.xprofile, .xsession, .xsessionrc` which all link to the first one via `ln -s`. I've tried to add `gnome-terminal &` for testing but the terminal didn't show up either, be it after either restarting `lightdm` or even the entire PC and logging in again.

I've also tried [Run configuration script at X session resume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298742/run-configuration-script-at-x-session-resume), but that gives the error `Can't open /usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs`.

Using `upstart`, as suggested by [Run a startup script with lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74189/run-a-startup-script-with-lightdm) wouldn't provide the xserver display variable (or handle?) either, just run it after `lightdm` started, correct?

Maybe put it somewhere in `xorg.conf`? ([How can I make xrandr customization permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent))
Beats me..

(My script makes quicklists of recent files and adds them to the unity launcher's rightclick-menues, similar to windows: https://github.com/thirschbuechler/ubuntu-recentquicklists)

Comment: Since your script is for making changes to the Unity launcher, presumably you want it to run when you login, right? See http://askubuntu.com/a/518440/158442 or http://askubuntu.com/a/500147/158442 (Also, which version of Ubuntu?)

Comment: Hi hirsch, did you notice you've got an answer?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: yes i noticed your answer, thank you! I have to try it out myself before upvoting tough, and will do so in the course of this week i hope. muru: thx too, i'll look into it. I have 14.04, but i want it to run on any ubuntu version, if possible

Comment: Please see this: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15051/please-take-your-own-questions-seriously Testing the answer takes 20 seconds + a restart.

Comment: apart from the fact that i discovered i have a different issue, you could have tested it yourself too, since i've provided the script, and seen that it doesn't work.  I am sorry, because i may have to rephrase my question @stackexchange since the problem seems to be linked to the dbus interface in pygtk.  My apologies

Comment: It's not my job to test nor to run a script. I didn't and I wouldn't. *If* the script runs from the terminal on your system, like you stated, I am pretty sure it works in the explained setup. Either it works in my setup or your statement was incorrect. You must do something wrong, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

As in many cases, timing is the main issue here.

1. Your script needs to run on user level *after log in*, since it edits launcher items, which is on user level.
2. Even then, looking at what the script should do (reading your explanation), the script needs to wait a bit for the desktop to fully load; the Unity Launcher is not the first thing to be "ready" after log in. If the script runs too early it will either break or miss target.

#### In short

You need to run the script appr. 10-15 seconds after log in, which can be done by adding either:

```bsh
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python /path/to/script.py"
```

(if the script is not executable), or

```bsh
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && /path/to/script.py"
```

(if the script *is* executable) to the user's Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add.

#### Run it for *all users*

If you need the script to run ***for all users*** (after log in), You can add it to Startup Applications for all users at once.

To do that, copy the code below into an empty file, edit the lines, starting with `Name=` and set the correct path to the script in the line:

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python /path/to/script.py"
```

then save the file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` as `launch_script.desktop` (or whatever you like, as long as it ends with `.desktop`)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Name
Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python /path/to/script.py"
Type=Application
```